# Redirect not including application name, and authentication not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm attempting to implement an "Admin" login so my users can add content on their own and I don't need to worry about a stranger somehow routing to a Create/Edit/Delete Action. Im putting the Username and password to authenticate against in the Web.config file and everything works fine in Visual Studio. But when I publish the application to IIS the authentication seems to fail and when redirecting back to the Login action I'm getting a `404 Not Found Error`. When redirecting or returning the View the route isn't including the Application name `{application name}/Authentication/Login` instead its just returning `Authentication/Login` but when I attempt to visit one of the Create actions it will successfully redirect, this is driving me insane and any help is much appreciated.

## RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Authentication",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Authentication", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

## AuthenticationController.cs

```
namespace ShipleySwine.Controllers
{
    public class AuthenticationController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Authentication
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(AuthenticationViewModel vm)
        {
            //if (ModelState.IsValid)
            //{
            //    if (vm.user.userName == System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Admin"].ToString() && vm.user.password == System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adminPass"].ToString())
            //    {
            //        Session["Authentication"] = "Success";
            //        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //        TempData["Message"] = "Login failed, Incorrect username/password";
            //        return Redirect("/ShipleySwine/Authentication/Login");
            //        //return RedirectToAction("Login", "Authentication");
            //    }
            //}
            //else
            //{
            //    //return RedirectToAction("Login", "Authentication");
            //    return Redirect("/ShipleySwine/Authentication/Login");
            //}

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (vm.user.userName == System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Admin"].ToString() && vm.user.password == System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["adminPass"].ToString())
                {
                    Session["Authentication"] = "Success";
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin");
                }
                else
                {
                    TempData["Message"] = "Login failed, Incorrect username/password";
                    ViewBag.Message = "Login failed, Incorrect username/password";
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Login.cshtml

```
@model ShipleySwine.ViewModels.AuthenticationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 50px; margin-top: 25px;" class="col-4 backgroundcolor rounded">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        <form action="/Authentication/Login" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
                <input name="user.userName" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input name="user.password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
            {
                <p class="text-danger font-weight-bold">@ViewBag.Message</p>
            }
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">

    </div>
</div>
```

## Web.config

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="Admin" value="{username}"/>
    <add key ="adminPass" value="{password}"/>
</appSettings>
```

## Create Action w/ successful Redirect

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            if(Session["Authentication"] != null)
            {
                if(Session["Authentication"].ToString() != "Success")
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Login", "Authentication");
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.BoarId = db.Boars.Max(boarid => boarid.Boar_Id) + 1;
                    return View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Authentication");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I didn't give myself enough time...

Figured it out after looking at it closely. I hardcoded the action in the `Login.cshtml`

```
<form action="/Authentication/Login" method="post">
```

This works just fine in Visual Studio running on Localhost but when published to IIS the route doesn't exist. In reality it wasn't redirecting because the form wasn't successfully passed to the controller

Correct `Login.cshtml`

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 50px; margin-top: 25px;" class="col-4 backgroundcolor rounded">
        <h2 class="text-center">Login</h2>
        @using (@Html.BeginForm("Login", "Authentication", FormMethod.Post))
        {

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
                <input name="user.userName" type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input name="user.password" type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            if (ViewBag.Message != null)
            {
                <p class="text-danger font-weight-bold">@ViewBag.Message</p>
            }
            <div class="text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>

        }
    </div>
```

with the important change being the tag helper `@using (@Html.BeginForm("Login", "Authentication", FormMethod.Post))`

Answer (score 0):

Just change your form to this :

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Login")" method="post">
```